# Batching up requests to a metrics server from ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, batch-processing, unicorn

Motivation:

I want to send continuous stats to our (custom built) metrics server and to keep to load down, batch those requests up and send them all at once every time, say, 50 requests have piled up.

Requirements:

- stat events across different processes have to reach the metrics server in order (we use unicorn with several workers)
- avoid use of any external queues if at all possible
- graceful handling of unresponsive metrics server (can happen)

Acknowledgements:

Just using an external queue (memcache, etc.) is the easy way out, but also one more thing we would need to scale/deploy/manage that I really don't want to put up with if avoidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is to use a dedicated queuing platform, as these provide message integrity and reliable transport.  Additionally, for any sufficiently large application messaging is a huge key to scalability. If you *really* have to bake it yourself froms scratch, your best bet would be to use the Celluloid library to handle thread management and us a time-based delay instead of a fixed queue limit.

Also, anything in the queue when you kill the app (eg to deploy) **will** be lost. Here's a rough implementation of one way to do it.

```
class MetricReporter
  include Celluloid

  def initialize
    @queue = Queue.new
  end

  def enqueue(metric)
    @queue << metric
    empty! if @queue.length > 50
  end

  def empty!
    until queue.length.zero?
      metric = @queue.pop
      #process metric
    end
  end
end
```

This is pretty easy to use, simply create an instance of MetricReporter in an initializer and enqueue metrics to it.

config/initializers/mymetrics.rb

```
METRIC_REPORTER = MetricReporter.new
```

app/models/myuser.rb

```
def login
  METRIC_REPORTER.enqueue({:action => 'User Logged In', :data => username})
end
```

Comment: This looks very promising, I will try it. As for your concern about the app being killed in a deploy, do you think, creating an at_exit that does the flush would cover this reliably (unless of course the app dies in a SIGKILL)?

Comment: I haven't had good luck using at_exit on a thread to protect it from dropping data on the floor. Using something like a write-ahead log is probably going to be your best bet to protect from data loss.